# MacTeX installation process

Tags: mactex

I recently installed the 2014 version of MacTeX and as I have limited space on my hard drive, I am wondering whether when one installs a new version of a distribution the old version is automatically deleted or if one has to delete it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering whether when one installs a new version of a distribution the old version is automatically deleted or if one has to delete it manually.

The latter option applies. MacTeX2015 will get installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2015`. If your computer is short on disk space, you'll want to delete the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2014`. This will have to be done manually, i.e., by you. The MacTeX installation process won't delete an old distribution automatically.